# Multi-Group Column Count Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have,

A list, `MyList`, of objects with fields:

```
string A;
string B;
```

Conceptually, this is similar to a two column SQL Table with columns A, B.

I'm trying to create a linq expression that would produce the three column result set of this T-SQL on such a conceptual table:

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(B) 
FROM T1
GROUP BY A, B
```

That is, if I had a table such as:

```
A       B
----------
x       g
x       g
x       g
x       s
y       g
y       g
```

I would expect:

```
A       B       COUNT(B)
-------------------------
x       g         3
x       s         1
y       g         2
```

My best efforts were this:

```
var result = from MyObjs in MyList
group MyObjs by new { MyObjs.A, MyObjs.B } into g
select new { g.Key.A, g.Key.B, g.Key.B.Count() }
```

But the count appears to return the total number of B's not the number of B's per multiple column group.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: The key thing to note is that you aren't really counting B, you are just counting (eg in the SQL `count(1)` would work just as well). This is why your answer intuitively doesn't work. NinjaNye has the solution nailed though it seems. :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this.... (off the top of my head)

```
var result = from MyObjs in MyList
group MyObjs by new { MyObjs.A, MyObjs.B } into g
select new { g.Key.A, g.Key.B, MyCount = g.Count() }
```

Or if you prefer...

```
var result = MyList.GroupBy(x => new {x.A, x.B})
                   .Select(g => new {g.Key.A, g.Key.B, MyCount = g.Count()});
```

Comment: Principle is correct but syntax is a little off on the last line. Should be `select new { A=g.Key.A, B=g.Key.B, Count=g.Count() }`

Comment: Only the calculated values (e.g. Count) must be named. Naming A and B is optional.